# Search and Replace question

Tags: text-processing, sed, search, replace

I need to find all occurrences of `AAsomeArbitraryStringBB` and replace it with `CCsomeArbitraryStringDD`.

So

```
AAHelloBB
Text
AAByeByeBB
```

becomes

```
CCHelloDD
Text
CCByeByeDD.
```

It's important to note that the replacement string contains part of the search string.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "native Linux command". Linux is a kernel. What's on top if it can differ between various systems. And even if two Linux based systems have the same program installed, these programs can be completely different, can be written in different languages, have different documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is basic task for `sed` command:

```
sed 's/AA\(someArbitraryString\)BB/CC\1DD/g'
```

Eventually if you want to do this for all "arbitrary strings":

```
sed 's/AA\(.*\)BB/CC\1DD/g'
```

Comment: thanks. the second command was the solution to my problem

Comment: Suppose *arbitrary strings* should be `[:alnum:]`

Comment: @mikeserv yes for future readers, if you don't mind. It looks quite complicated.

Comment: ok, jimmij, I think that does. While tooling it over I realized I could simplify it in a big way - it doesn't need to nest any sub-expressions any more.

Answer (score 2):

```
sed "s/\([AB]\)\1\1*/\n&\n/g
     s/AA\n\([[:alnum:]]\{1,\}\)\nBB/CC\1DD/g
     s/\n//g
" <<\INPUT
AAHelloBB Text AAByeByeBB
INPUT
```

I think that should only do the `AA>>CC&&BB>>DD` replacement if there is 1 or more alphanumeric character[s] between the two groups and should always squeeze the possible occurrences as near to each other as it might.

The example prints:

```
CCHelloDD Text CCByeByeDD
```

The hard part of this is done is in the first `s///`ubstitution statement. It places a `\n`ewline character at the head and tail of all `AAA*` and `BBB*` occurrences in pattern space simultaneously. Delimiting can be tricky sometimes - often placing a head-end delimiter can change where a tail-end delimiter should go or vice-versa. I try to take that step in a single bound whenever possible to avoid having to edit an edit.

So we'll look at it inside out, but as we do consider that `sed` is scanning pattern space from left-to-right for every occurrence of the resultant pattern because I tack the `g`lobal flag onto the tail of `s///`ubstitution statement.

- `[AB]` - `sed` will pause its scan when encountering the first `A` or `B` in any series of either as it scans. It will next look for...
- `\([AB]\)\1\1*` - at least one immediately subsequent identical character and any/all continuing identical characters for as long as the sequence can last. I group the `[AB]` character class in a `\(`sub-expression`\)` and so can refer to its contents with the back-reference `\1`.

  - This is different than doing `[AB]\{2,\}` or even `\([AB]\)\{2,\}` as in those cases `sed` will consider both `A` and `B` to match the pattern. Rather here all characters added to the match group are identical to the first match on `[AB]`.
- `\n&\n` - in the right-hand-side of the `s///`ubstitution I reference the entire sequence just matched with `&` and insert at its head and tail a `\n`ewline character.

  - Many `sed`s will not support a `\n`ewline backslash escape in the right-hand-side of a substitution. If this is the case for you you can simply use a literal `\n`ewline character in place the `n` instead.

Here is a `l`ook at the results of this `s///`ubstitution on the example input string:

```
\nAA\nHello\nBB\n Text \nAA\nByeBye\nBB\n
```

You can see that other than inserting extra `\n`ewline characters *(which is pretty much the only character that can only occur in a `sed` pattern space as a result of an edit)* `sed` has not altered the string at all - no input character is modified.

You can also see that every `AAA*` or `BBB*`sequence is now immediately enclosed within `\n`ewlines. So when I do the next `g`lobal `s///`ubstitution I just have to tell `sed` to...

- `AA\n` - begin each match only at the tail end of a `AAA*` sequence immediately followed by...
- `\([[:alnum:]]\{1,\}\)` - one or more alphanumeric characters. This should never work out to be a `BBB*` sequence because where `AAA*` immediately precedes `BBB*` there are now *two* intermediate `\n`ewlines betwixt them. This alphanumeric sequence must be immediately followed by...
- `\nBB` - the head end of a `BBB*` sequence.

And in the right-hand-side...

- `CC\1DD` - we replace `AA\n` w/ `CC` `\1` with itself and `\nBB` w/ `DD`.

At this point a `l`ook reveals...

```
\nCCHelloDD\n Text \nCCByeByeDD\n
```

...apparent success! We now need only to do...

```
`s/\n//g`
```

...and remove any remaining `\n`ewline delimiters and the work is done.

Here's the result of my hammering randomly at the keyboard for a seconds rendered as input. It is a far more complicated input example so I split it out with escaped `\n`ewlines in a here-document. The shell will remove all the newlines you can see here before passing the single line result to `sed` as input:

```
sed ... <<IN
AA  kj \
BB\
AAAAAABAkl\
AAAAasjd\
AAAAfo\
BB\
AAia\
BBsdfjomAl\
BBks\
BBmdlmdsviom\
BB\
AAiodsvgmnoi
IN
```

...and a `l`ook following the first `s///`ubstitution:

```
\nAA\n kj \nBB\n\nAAAAAA\nBAkl\nAAAA\nasjd\nAAAA\nfo\nBB\n\nAA\nia\nBB\nsdfjomAl\nBB\nks\nBB\nmdlmdsviom\nBB\n\nAA\niodsvgmnoi
```

...and following the second...

```
\nAA\n kj \nBB\n\nAAAAAA\nBAkl\nAAAA\nasjd\nAACCfoDD\n\nCCiaDD\nsdfjomAl\nBB\nks\nBB\nmdlmdsviom\nBB\n\nAA\niodsvgmnoi
```

...and the final product...

```
AA kj BBAAAAAABAklAAAAasjdAACCfoDDCCiaDDsdfjomAlBBksBBmdlmdsviomBBAAiodsvgmnoi
```