# Regex pattern search for alternating character case

Tags: grep, regular-expression

How would I pipe the `ls` through `grep` to have an alternating character case, as output?

---

For example:

I have files (1) aAbBaBbA, (2) bAbBaA, (3) bbAb,(4) AAaBbAa,(5) BBBaaa, and (6) aBaB.

I want to find 1,2,6.

---

What command would I type?

**(Edit)**: My example wasn't as specific as it should have been. I wanted to include alternating starting with lower and upper. (6) should be changed from **aBaB** to **BaBa**, but I want to keep the original.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
set aAbBaBbA bAbBaA bbAb AAaBbAa BBBaaa aBaB
l= u=;  printf %s\\n    "$@" |
        grep -E "^([${l:=[:lower:]}][${u:=[:upper:]}])+[$l]?$|^([$u][$l])+[$u]?$"
```

#### OUTPUT:

```
aAbBaBbA
bAbBaA
aBaB
```

But see Pierre's answer for the *(obviously)* better version of this.

Still, there is another way:

```
grep -vE '[^[:alpha:]]|[[:lower:]]{2}|[[:upper:]]{2}|^$'
```

...though that will match only a single char on a line. You can fix that by doing a `.?` between the `^` and `$` at the end though.

Comment: was hoping to do this without a script :) otherwise I would have checked with python.. but I think I could use the regex you have in there

Comment: @NoTime - You can do it without a script - the `for` loop is just to get it all over to `grep` but actually, that's not the best way to do it....

Comment: I changed it to full command, I still don't fully understand why range from A-Z wouldn't work

Comment: @NoTime - it *might*, but that is a locale specific range - A-Z and a-z depend on the C locale's sort order by ASCII byte value - if you start working with locales in which that is not true, `[[:lower:]]` and `[[:upper:]]` are the robust classes - so you might as well just do it robustly from the start.

Comment: I honestly started with those from the start, but was unable to get past repeating characters without having to redirect the output into a file, then append with a different regex.

Comment: @NoTime - I think it might go back to the pattern vs reference confusion... There might be something in [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/178783/52934) that could help clear that up.

Comment: @NoTime - actually, now that I think about it, even this fails for odd numbers of characters. I'll fix that...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20596/discussion-between-no-time-and-mikeserv).

Answer (score 5):

try

```
ls -1 | grep -E '^[A-Z]?([a-z][A-Z])*[a-z]?$'
```

EDIT: as pointed very correctly by @mikeserv, this won't work for non-ASCII chars. And indeed they do happen quite often (e.g. music files with foreign titles for filename).  So the more robust way is:

```
ls -1 | grep -E '^[[:upper:]]?([[:lower:]][[:upper:]])*[[:lower:]]?$'
```

In the following, I retain just `[A-Z]` for sake of readability.

Also, a caveat: this will match a single char (upper or lower). One could argue that "alternating case" is defined by no successive similar case in a sequence of zero or more chars...  :-)

Test:

```
mkdir -p /tmp/junk
cd /tmp/junk
touch aAbBaBbA bAbBaA bbAb AAaBbAa BBBaaa aBaB

ls -1 | grep -E '^[A-Z]?([a-z][A-Z])*[a-z]?$'
# aAbBaBbA
# aBaB
# bAbBaA
```

But that's not enough. Some more tests:

```
touch aB
touch aBcD
touch aBcDeF
touch aBcDEf
touch Ab
touch AbCd
touch AbCdEf
touch AbCdeF
touch AbCdEF
ls -1 | grep -E '^[A-Z]?([a-z][A-Z])*[a-z]?$'
# aAbBaBbA
# aB
# Ab
# aBaB
# aBcD
# AbCd
# aBcDeF
# AbCdEf
# bAbBaA
```

Comment: This matches blank lines.

Comment: @mikeserv I don't often have filenames that are blank...

Comment: mmh, on the other hand it will match single character either upper or lower. My bad.

Comment: I'm not convinced a single char should be a failing case though - it is still alternating case, I think. There just isn't enough of it to fill out the pattern entirely... I guess @NoTime will probably chime in tomorrow.

Comment: @mikeserv: lol.  Yeah, I guess "alternating case" could be zero or more characters, such that two consecutive characters with the same case cannot occur... :-)

Comment: Yes - it is definitely what mine should have been - excepting that the robust way is to use `[[:upper:]][[:lower:]]` to avoid locale problems. Use a `+` rather than the Kleene `*` and you avoid the blank line thing.

Comment: @mikeserv +1 for the char class. Indeed, more robust and it isn't just a fine point. I have tons of mp3 files, for example, named with lovely accents and other non-ascii chars. I have trying to answer something very readable in terms of the logic of it.

Comment: @mikeserv I guess technically it would be an alternating case if you think of it like (0,1). I would think of this more as a filter limiting repeating character cases. But  it is as correct this way. Just need to do ÜüÜüÜüÜüÜ and üÜüÜüÜüÜ now :P

Comment: @NoTime that's what this regexp allows: `u,U,uU,Uu,uUu,UuU,...`. Filtered out are all sequences with any repeated consecutive case.

Comment: @PierreD ah yes.. I am American, silly of me to think for some reason umlauts were considered as being special characters.

Comment: Pierre - yes, with the POSIX classes it should pretty well assure that - it was well done. Mine was your second upvote here - it's pretty good. I would be interested to see a performance comparison between it and the `-v` option in mine - my suspicion is the `-v` would take it because it only has to find and rule out 2 consecutive characters anywhere in the string - but because the regexp engine will be reading left-right anyway I have my doubts as well because it might add up to the same thing. @NoTime - umlauts *are* as special as you want them to be, of course.

Answer (score 3):

Type this command:

`ls |grep -E '^([[:upper:]][[:lower:]])+[[:upper:]]?$|^([[:lower:]][[:upper:]])+[[:lower:]]?$'`

To break this down.

- `ls` is the main command
- It is piped to `grep`
- The switch `-P` or `-E` are telling `grep` to search using regular expressions (regex)
- Within the single quote <kbd>'</kbd> and the parentheses <kbd>()</kbd> the pattern is layed out.
- Basically it reads match any upper letter `[[:upper:]]` then any smaller letter `[[:lower:]]`
- **Or** using the pipe <kbd>|</kbd>
- Then match any smaller letter `[[:lower:]]` then match any upper letter `[[:upper:]]`
- The `+` will match everything within the parentheses <kbd>()</kbd> and play it out through the list given.
- `$` tells when the pattern ends

Comment: Have you tried that? Both commands match (6) only.

Comment: @HaukeLaging yes I just spent most of the day doing it. My answer worked for me.

Comment: What `grep` are you using? Mine is GNU grep 2.20

Comment: @HaukeLaging Version 2.21 http://imgur.com/0B3AquK is results. I also matched it online at regexr.com

Answer (score 0):

The solution is

```
grep -E '^([a-z][A-Z])+$'
```

Comment: This one did not work for me I only returned 2 items. Ill post a screen shot

Comment: Won't match the alternating case: 'Ab'.

Comment: @PierreD Correct but that's not a bug. None of the matching examples looks like that.

Comment: @HaukeLaging Mmh. The fact that it isn't given as example doesn't make it less of an "alternating case character sequence".  Examples are not the rule, they just, you know, _illustrate_ the idea...

Comment: @PierreD That is correct but very theoretical. You never know (without asking) whether the description or the examples are the better description of the intention. I have been around here for a while. I am quite familiar with that problem.